# What is the meaning of "due to the symmetry of the coefficients, if $x=r$ is a zero of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ then $x=\frac1r$ is also a zero"

Tags: polynomials, factoring, symmetry, quartics

I was studying this answer about factoring $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$:

https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-factor-x-4-x-3-x-2-x-1

The author says: "A cleaner algebraic approach is to notice that due to the symmetry of the coefficients, if $x=r$ is a zero of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ then $x= {1\over r}$ is also a zero"

And eventually he writes  $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)$

Question $1$: What is the meaning of symmetry of the coefficients?

Question $2$: Can we do the same approach for $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$? ( I ask because it is relevant to my other question: [Problem with factoring $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3792586))

Comment: It means $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$ implies ${1\over x}^4+{1\over x}^3+{1\over x}^2+{1\over x}+1=0$ and also the other way around.

Comment: Think of it as $x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4$ (with $y=1$); it has symmetry $x\leftrightarrow y$. Same holds for the other polynomial.

Comment: It is basically the same equation when you substitute $x\to \frac1x \, , x\ne 0$ in that polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of coefficients of$$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$$is $(1,1,1,1,1)$, which is symmetric (if you reverse it, you will get the same list). In other words, it is a list of the type $(a,b,c,b,a)$. And if $r(\ne0)$ is a root of$$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+bx+a,\tag1$$then$$ar^4+br^3+cr^2+br+a=0,$$and therefore$$a+\frac br+\frac c{r^2}+\frac b{r^3}+\frac a{r^4}=0$$too; in other words, $\frac1r$ is also a root of $(1)$. So, unless one of the roots is $\pm1$ (which are the only numbers equal to their own inverses), $(1)$ can be written as\begin{multline}a(x-r)\left(x-\frac1r\right)(x-r')\left(x-\frac1{r'}\right)=\\=a\left(x^2-\left(r+\frac1r\right)x+1\right)\left(x^2-\left(r'+\frac1{r'}\right)x+1\right).\end{multline}

In particular, $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ can be written as$$(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)=x^4+(a+b)x^3+(ab+2)x^2+(a+b)x+1.$$In order to find $a$ and $b$, solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+b=-1\\ab+2=1.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Given a degree-$4$ polynomial of the form (1), it might be worth saying something about what happens if a root $r$ satisfies $r = \frac{1}{r}$. We can immediately see that $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$ must appear with the same parity, since the degree is even and all other factors appear in pairs $(x-s)(x-\frac{1}{s})$. And then it's easy to show that in fact this parity must be even...but maybe some mention of this could be included? (So for example, how do we know that the factorization can't be $a(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x-\frac{1}{2})$?)

Comment: @mathmandan Nice point. I have added that what I wrote works when none of the roots is $\pm1$.

Comment: Thanks!  Actually it can still be salvaged, I think: it seems to me that you can't have $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$ appear exactly once each, because then the constant term of the polynomial will be $(-a)$ rather than $a$ (and certainly $a\neq -a$, otherwise $a=0$ and the polynomial would not have degree $4$).

Comment: @mathmandan Note that the final goal was to solve the equation $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=0$. Since neither $1$ nor $-1$ are roots of that equation, there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the original question, the thinking process comes as follows:

(1) If $r$ is a solution to $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=0$, then $r^4-r^3+r^2-r+1=0$.

(2) Divide both sides by $r^4$ you get $({1\over r})^4-({1\over r})^3+({1\over r})^2-({1\over r})+1=0$. Therefore $1\over r$ is also a solution.

(3) Hence if $(x-r)$ is a factor of the polynomial then $(x-{1\over r})$ is also a factor.

(4) Therefore the equation can be written as $(x-r)(x-{1\over r})(x-s)(x-{1\over s})$

(5) Therefore it can be written as $(x+ax+1)(x+bx+1)$

Comment: Maybe point out initially that $1$ and $-1$ are not solutions to the original equation.  Therefore $r\neq \frac{1}{r}$, so in (3) we know that $(x-r)$ and $(x-\frac{1}{r})$ are not the same factor, and we get the factorization in (4).